# Informatica HTTP Transformation status

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a mapping with HTTP transformation. How can i get request status code (e.g. 200 (OK) when request is successful or 404 (Not Found) when server is down)?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In case the Status Code is not "200 OK", the record is dropped at the HTTP transformation. The response status code displayed in the session log.

I don't think you can capture the status code inside the mapping using HTTP transformation. This is because, the status comes as a seperate status line instead of regular http header field.